# Transient Polly retry not working for HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-response-codes, polly

I want to implement a polly retry with transient error handling. I amuse the bellow code should work but retry is not firing.

Please let me know where i am wrong.

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                                           || r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout
                                           || r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout
                                           || r.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
    .WaitAndRetry(3, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Request failed with {result.Result.StatusCode}. Waiting {timeSpan} before next retry. Retry attempt {retryCount}");
    });

    retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
    {
        response = FailedOperation();
        return response;
    });
   
     private static HttpResponseMessage FailedOperation()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception !!!!!");
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

The custom `FailedOperation()` method does not involve any of the related .NET framework /ASP.NET infrastructure, so the code execution you are testing will not magically convert:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout);
```

to an `HttpResponseMessage` with a `StatusCode`.  Polly does not do this either (Polly is generic to any delegate execution, not tied to http executions).  The `FailedOperation()` method you have posted just throws an `HttpResponseException`, pure and simple.

The policy is not declared to handle `HttpResponseException` so it does not handle it.  Add a clause `.Or<HttpResponseException>()` like this:

```
var retryPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => /* etc */)
    .Or<HttpResponseException>();
```

and the policy should handle it and make the test code behave as I think the question expects.  Alternatively, you could modify `FailedOperation()` to return an `HttpResponseMessage` with an `HttpStatusCode` the policy handles, and again, the test code should behave as expected.

Finally, if the policy is to guard async calls through `HttpClient` you would want to use [async variants of policies](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Asynchronous-action-execution) as the [Polly readme examples around Http calls suggest](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#step-1b-optionally-specify-return-results-you-want-to-handle).

Comment: can i give multiple conditions in handle request because in my case i have specify 3-4 conditions in handle request but in that case polly retry is not working thats why i dont want to use .Or<HttpResponseException>(); because in that case my specified condition are working for every  HttpResponseException

Comment: You can give multiple conditions and they work (my answer described why your posted case did not behave as expected; it is not to do with multiple conditions). You can also use conditions in the `.Or<HttpResponseException>()` clause to filter more finely, as [shown here in the documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#step-1--specify-the--exceptionsfaults-you-want-the-policy-to-handle). Polly has unit-tests proving these aspects work. If something else is not working as expected, please provide new [example failing code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).